# Heroku Ruby on Rails app don't updates non-digested assets in public/assets dir

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have Ruby on Rails application on heroku.

We are using ruby `2.1.5`

```
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
```

And Ruby on Rails `4.1.1`

Gemfile:
http://codepad.org/6YwcIHYL

Sprockets version (extract from `gemfile.lock`):

```
sprockets (2.11.0)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
```

---

Of course we are using digested assets

e.g. `application-d99ed24f47c5c39b96889148558cb16c.js` - THEY are working

Besides that, I am using non-digested assets for CKEditor,

I put them under `RAILS_ROOT/public/assets` directory

so `/assets/ckeditor/config.js` should point to `RAILS_ROOT/public/assets/ckeditor/config.js`

---

**Issue**

I can't update assets under `public/assets`

I updated one file from CKEditor, but it doesn't show the changes either when I:

- fetch file via CURL
- look at source in incognito window at chrome (incognito -> 'avoid' caching)

I commited the changes, build on CircleCI passes (continuous integration service). Auto-deploy updates the staging server.

But I still get the old file.

MOREOVER I looked at source of the file using `heroku run bash`

```
heroku run bash
cd public/assets/ckeditor
cat config.js
```

and it RETURNS the old version. Changing this via various `tricks` e.g. `rm` `cp` `echo NEW_CONTENT >> NEW_FILE.js` also doesn't work.

Heroku returns old version...

**PS** Moving CKEditor from `public/assets/ckeditor` to `app/assets/ckeditor` didn't solve the issue.

---

**UPDATE**

application.js content: http://codepad.org/ZpBruQt9

But CKeditor `config.js` file (`public/assets/ckeditor/config.js`) is not included in `application.js`.

It is non-digest asset :)

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't let you store files in its dyno, any file that you might have edited gets reseted every 15 minutes. So changing it directly via rm, cp, echo won't do the trick. The file has to be tracked by your git branch.

May i suggest using the ckeditor gem, which would play nicely with sprockets (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), that should definitly help you fix your problem.

Comment: Hi **@Coderhs**! Unfortunately we can't switch easily to this gem, because we are using `custom` build of CKeditor. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: Just confirming: the ckeditor files are included in your application.js right? if its not there in application.js is it directly included and precompiled?. Can you include your application.js @nothing-special-here

Comment: try this changing, #=require ckeditor/ckeditor to #= require_tree ./ckeditor/ckeditor. I assume that you moved your ckeditor from public to app/javascripts